Creating Column Json data at Laravel Backpack
This is inside my Column 'reviewsDistribution' @myDataBase
{
    "oneStar": 0,
    "twoStar": 0,
    "threeStar": 1,
    "fourStar": 2,
    "fiveStar": 10
}

It's a json type column
I wanted to show this at Create Method
I've tried:
$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'reviewsDistribution',
    'label' => 'reviewsDistribution',
    'type' => 'table',
    'entity_singular' => 'reviewsDistribution', // used on the "Add X" button
    'columns' => [
        'key' => 'Key',
        'value' => 'value',
    ],
    'max' => 5,
    'min' => 1,
]);

But I does not shows the values, there is only one row and It's Empty

Also, if i fill this rows it gives me then, in a later page, an error:
htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

And in the database there is one ARRAY OF OBJETCS saved.... not an Object, as I had before
[
    {
        "key": "s1",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "key": "s2",
        "value": "2"
    }
]

That column is casted as an array in the Model
 protected $casts = [
        'reviewsDistribution' => 'array',

Also, in Mysql, that column has an "json" type


This question is similar to: Creating and Updating Column Json data. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The answers in that question does not resolves the issue.
type=> array is not a correct answer
And type=table does not shows my data as is suposed to be
